# Import csv file into MSAccess using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import, ms-access-2016

I have a csv file that I need to import into MS Access.  I am using VBA.  The specific line of script I am using is

`DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "csvImport", sFileOut, False`

The file imports, however, some of the field data is missing.  It appears that the import process transforms 1-20-0032 to 1/20/0032 and 1-23-WRTY to NULL.

As a quick example, if my csv file contains the following...

A, 1-20-0032, 2-101, 03/12/2023, 03/17/2023, 10, 439.9
A, 1-23-WRTY, 50-200, 03/12/2023, 03/17/2023, 16, 852

It comes into the table like this...

A | 1/20/0032 | 2-101 | 03/12/2023 | 03/17/2023 | 10 | 439.9 |
A |           | 2-101 | 03/12/2023 | 03/17/2023 | 10 | 439.9 |

Everything is working fine except the value 1-23-WRTY

I have resolved the issue of 1-23-0032 importing as 1/20/0032 by updating "/" to "-" for values in that column after the import is complete.  However, I don't know how to get round the values that are not importing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!

If I manually import the csv file, I can get the values to come through.
However, user needs to be able to click a button to import the file.  So that does not work.
I have tried using VBA to import into the same table created through the manual process.  Does not work.  Even though the field is set to short text, it will bring that column in with / instead of - and drop the field data that ends with letters. (It appears to always think that the field is a date.  In import specs I indicated that date identifier is /.  However, on import it still replaces - with /

Comment: The second parameter of `DoCmd.TransferText` is `SpecificationName` and you can save the import specification when you import the file (correctly?) manually. You can then use the import specification after that and the file should be imported in the same way. If that does not work manually set the field 1-23-WRTY to import as text and then fix the import afterwards in code as you did for 1-23-0032.

Comment: I had tried with and without a Specification and I still could not get it to work prior to posting my question.  Even if the field type is text, it still brings the data in as a date since some of the data contains alpha instead of numeric values, the import just ingnores them.  I end up with nothing in the data field to modify.  I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The DoCmd.TransferText trys to decide best data type from the first n rows.

That columns are being read as a date, and when the "date" is invalid, it imports null.

try to put a file schema.ini in the same folder where you have te txt file to import,and put this options

---

[NAME_OFF_THE_FILE_TO_IMPORT.txt]

ColNameHeader=True

Format=CSVDelimited

MaxScanRows=0

CharacterSet=ANSI

---

MaxScanRows=0 will force the DoCmd.TransferText to read all file to decide best data type

Comment: I have nevered paired an ini file with MS Access.  Therefore, I will give that a go and report back!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: I liked this soution.  However, I could not get it to work.

Comment: I first used the MaxScanRows=0.  The value came in as a date.  Then I tried to define the columns with Coln.  I set all the fields to text.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  This looked straight forward but I must be missing something.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need it, here is a bespoke method of reading the data you have shown as an example.
This reads one character at a time so may be useful if the input data is likely to have random gaps, for example.
Also the error handling is useful for highlighting unexpected errors in the input data.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub sbImportCSV()
MsgBox fnBulkInsertComma("C:\Users\david\Desktop\1-23-WRTY.csv")
End Sub

' A, 1-20-0032, 2-101, 03/12/2023, 03/17/2023, 10, 439.9
' A, 1-23-WRTY, 50-200, 03/12/2023, 03/17/2023, 16, 852
' f1  f2         f3       f4         f5         f6   f7
' ---------!---------!---------!---------!---------!---------!---------!---------!
' 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903106/import-csv-file-into-msaccess-using-vba

Public Function fnBulkInsertComma(sFilename As String)
 On Error GoTo fnBulkInsertComma_Error_Routine

 Dim sErrFilename As String
 sErrFilename = "C:\Users\david\Desktop\err" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHHMMSS") & ".txt"

 Dim i As Long
 Dim s As String
 Dim sComma As String
 Dim sInputChar As String
 Dim sSQL01 As String
 Dim sSQL02 As String
 Dim f As Integer

 If fnTableExists("tblBulkInsert") Then DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE tblBulkInsert"
 DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE tblBulkInsert (" & _
    "f1 varchar, f2 varchar, f3 varchar, f4 varchar, f5 varchar," & _
    "f6 varchar," & _
    "f7 varchar," & _
    "f8 varchar," & _
    "f9 varchar," & _
    "f10 varchar," & _
    "f11 varchar," & _
    "f12 varchar," & _
    "f13 varchar," & _
    "f14 varchar," & _
    "f15 varchar," & _
    "f16 varchar," & _
    "f17 varchar," & _
    "f18 varchar," & _
    "f19 varchar," & _
    "f20 varchar," & _
    "f21 varchar," & _
    "f22 varchar," & _
    "f23 varchar," & _
    "f24 varchar," & _
    "f25 varchar," & _
    "f26 varchar" & _
    ");"

 i = 1
 f = 1
 s = ""
 sComma = ","
 sInputChar = ""
 sSQL01 = ""
 sSQL02 = ""

 Open sFilename For Input As #10
    Do Until EOF(10)
        sInputChar = Input(1, #10)      ' read one character at a time
        If Asc(sInputChar) < 127 Then   ' sInputChar is a control character
            If sInputChar = "'" Then    ' always remove single quotes
                                        ' because of interference with SQL syntax
                GoTo Next_Char
            End If
            If sInputChar = sComma Then ' this is a field delimiter
                If f = 1 Then
                    sSQL01 = "INSERT INTO tblBulkInsert (f1"
                    sSQL02 = "VALUES ('" & s & "'"
                End If
                If f > 1 Then
                    sSQL01 = sSQL01 & ",f" & f
                    sSQL02 = sSQL02 & ",'" & s & "'"
                End If
                s = ""
                f = f + 1
                GoTo Next_Char
            End If
            If sInputChar = vbCr Then
                sSQL01 = sSQL01 & ",f" & f & ") "
                sSQL02 = sSQL02 & ",'" & s & "');"
                sSQL01 = sSQL01 & sSQL02
                DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL01
                s = ""
                sSQL01 = ""
                sSQL02 = ""
                f = 1
                GoTo Next_Char
            End If
            If sInputChar = vbLf Then
                s = ""
                GoTo Next_Char
            End If
            s = s & sInputChar          ' add each character to the input field
        End If
Next_Char:
        i = i + 1
    Loop

fnBulkInsertComma_Exit_Routine:
 Close #10
 Exit Function

fnBulkInsertComma_Error_Routine:
 Open sErrFilename For Output As #9
 Print #9, "Error Log - 3rd April 2023"
 Print #9, Now()
 Print #9, Err.Number
 Print #9, Err.Description
 Print #9, CurrentDb.Name
 Print #9, "fnBulkInsertComma"
 Print #9, sInputChar
 Print #9, s
 Print #9, sSQL01
 Print #9, sSQL02
 Print #9, "**END**"

 Close #9
 Resume fnBulkInsertComma_Exit_Routine

End_Function:
End Function

Public Function fnTableExists(sTablename As String) As Boolean
 On Error GoTo Exit_Function
 fnTableExists = False
 If IsObject(CurrentDb.TableDefs(sTablename)) Then fnTableExists = True
Exit_Function:
End Function
```

Here is the DDL for the tblResults (my system works using UK format dates)

```
CREATE TABLE [tblResults] (
 [r1] VARCHAR(1), 
 [r2] VARCHAR(9), 
 [r3] VARCHAR(255), 
 [r4] DATETIME, 
 [r5] VARCHAR(15), 
 [r6] LONG DEFAULT 0, 
 [r7] SINGLE DEFAULT 0
);
```

You may need this SELECT query,

```
SELECT tblBulkInsert.f1, 
tblBulkInsert.f2, 
tblBulkInsert.f3, 
tblBulkInsert.f4, 
tblBulkInsert.f5, 
tblBulkInsert.f6, 
tblBulkInsert.f7 
FROM tblBulkInsert;
```

and the following APPEND query,

```
INSERT INTO tblResults ( r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7 )
SELECT [qrySelect-f1-f7].f1, [qrySelect-f1-f7].f2, [qrySelect-f1-f7].f3, 
[qrySelect-f1-f7].f4, [qrySelect-f1-f7].f5, [qrySelect-f1-f7].f6, 
[qrySelect-f1-f7].f7
FROM [qrySelect-f1-f7];
```