# Excel VBA - Insert worksheets into SQL Database

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-express

Hello im new to VBA and im struggling a bit, so i need your help.

About the requirements:
Every day a special csv file is updated by our CRM.
From this Excel table 4 columns are to be written into a database. All contents of the cells are strings.

The table name in the SQL database should be the name of the respective worksheet.
In the Excel table there are some cells which start with a " # ", " ' " or " _ ". The VBA code should ignore these when transferring to the database.

The VBA code should be adapted so that all new columns that are added over time are automatically recognized and written to the database.
All contents of these columns are to be represented in the future also as string.

There will be several worksheets with time (currently 2), which the VBA code should run through automatically. However, the column names are not always identical from the worksheets.
If there is a new worksheet, it should create this as a table in the database and run through exactly the same procedure.

With each new search run only changes should be transferred and no duplicate entries should be made.

This is my test code, which was working.

```
Option Explicit

Public cn As ADODB.Connection

Sub ProcessData()

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim id As Integer
Dim Row number of Article As String
Dim SM001 As String
Dim SM004 As String
Dim SM013 As String

Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=Testserver2019; Database=Work2023; Trusted_Connection=yes"

Dim lastRow As Double
Dim row As Double
Dim ws As Integer

    cn.Open strConn
    StrSQL = "Truncate table dbo.MyTable"
    cn.Execute StrSQL

    For ws = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        wsName = Worksheets(ws).Name
        'MsgBox (wsName)
        'activating each worksheet in order to iterate through data
         Worksheets(wsName).Activate
        
        'going to very first cell of worksheet to get last row to find out range
         Cells(1, 1).Select
    
        'fetching last row so that we can iterate through each & every cell
         lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
         
         For row = 2 To lastRow
            
               Row number of article = Cells(row, 1).Value
               SM001 = Cells(row, 2).Value
               SM004 = Cells(row, 3).Value
               SM013 = Cells(row, 4).Value
            
               StrSQL = "insert into dbo.MyTable(id, name, code, city) values(" _
               + Str(Row number of Article) + "," _
               + "'" + SM001 + "'," _
               + "'" + SM004 + "'," _
               + "'" + SM013 + "'" _
               + ")"
               
               'MsgBox (StrSQL)
               
               cn.Execute StrSQL
            
         Next row
         
         'MsgBox (StrSQL)
    
    
    Next
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    MsgBox ("Process is finished...")

End Sub
```

Unfortunately these entries are still rendered with # , ' or _. Which is of course clear, since I don't have the condition in my VBA code yet.
Hence the question can I do this with the command or is there a better way:

```
For row = 2 To lastRow
                If Left(.Cells(row, 1).Value, 1) <> "#" And Left(.Cells(row, 1).Value, 1) <> "'" And Left(.Cells(row, 1).Value, 1) <> "_" Then
                    Row number of article = .Cells(row, 1).Value
                    SM001 = .Cells(row, 2).Value
                    SM004 = .Cells(row, 3).Value
                    SM013 = .Cells(row, 4).Value
```

Some more questions:
How do I get the columns to be automatically recognized and written to the database?

How do I get Excel to run through all available worksheets and create them as a table in the database?

How do I make sure that it does not populate the table with duplicate entries each time, but only updates the tables during the next scan?

The VBA code should also intentionally take cells that are not yet filled as an empty field into the database.

Comment: Why don't the variables SM001, SM004, SM013 appear in the `StrSQL = ` statement if they are the name, code, city values ?

Comment: Use this answer and load the .CSV file directly into the SQL Server database using MS Access. MS Access will link to SQL Server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903106/import-csv-file-into-msaccess-using-vba/75930652#75930652

Comment: @CDP1802 I have forgotten to change the values here, im sorry.

Comment: @user10186832 I´m sorry i have to do it via VBA

Comment: Are the table field names in the first row of the sheet ? Is the first column always the primary key ie has a value unique to that specific record ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, in the 1st row there are the field names of the sheet. 
The primary key is always the "Row number of article" and is in column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How do I make sure that it does not populate the table with duplicate entries each time, but only updates the tables during the next scan?* '. Delete any existing record with same primary key before inserting the new record.

Note : Records deleted from the spreadsheet won't be deleted from the database.

Edit 1 : Primary Key as BigInt

```vb
Option Explicit

Const PK = "Row number of article"
Public cn As ADODB.Connection

Sub ProcessData()
    
    Set cn = DbConnect("TestServer2019", "Work2023")
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, cmdDel As Command
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, sql As String, t As String
    Dim n As Long, lastrow As Long, r As Long
    Dim numIns As Long, numDel As Long
    Dim msg As String, bExists As Boolean
    Dim colField As Collection, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' build dictionary of existing tables in database
    Dim dictTable As Object, k
    Set dictTable = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME " & _
          "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES " & _
          "WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'"
           
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        t = rs.Fields(0)
        rs.MoveNext
        dictTable.Add t, 0
        'msg = msg & vbLf & t
    Loop
    'MsgBox "Existing Tables " & msg
    
    ' loop through sheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' does table exist
        bExists = dictTable.exists(ws.Name)
        If bExists = False Then
            If ws.Cells(1, 1) = PK Then
                sql = BuildCreateSQL(ws)
                'If vbYes = MsgBox("Create Table " & ws.Name & vbLf & sql, vbYesNo, "Confirm") Then
                    'Debug.Print sql
                    cn.Execute sql
                    bExists = True ' table exists
                'End If
            Else
                MsgBox ws.Name & " cell A1 must be " & PK, vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
        
        ' update records
        If bExists = True Then
        
            ' build insert query
            Set colField = New Collection
            sql = BuildSQL(ws, colField)
            'Debug.Print ws.Name, sql
            
            ' build insert command
            Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
            With cmd
                .CommandText = sql
                .ActiveConnection = cn
                For n = 1 To colField.Count
                   If n = 1 Then
                      .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P" & n, adBigInt, adParamInput)
                   Else
                      .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P" & n, adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
                   End If
                Next
            End With
            
             ' build delete command
            Set cmdDel = New ADODB.Command
            With cmdDel
                .ActiveConnection = cn
                .CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo." & ws.Name & _
                              " WHERE [" & PK & "] = ?"
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P" & n, adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
            End With
             
            ' scan down sheet deleting / inserting rows
            With ws
                lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
                For r = 2 To lastrow
                     ' assign parameter values
                     For n = 1 To cmd.Parameters.Count
                         cmd.Parameters(n - 1).Value = NoHash(.Cells(r, colField(n)))
                     Next
                     
                     ' delete if existing and insert
                     cmdDel.Parameters(0).Value = .Cells(r, 1) ' primary key in col 1
                     cmdDel.Execute n
                     numDel = numDel + n
                     cmd.Execute n
                     numIns = numIns + n
                Next
            End With
                      
            Set cmd = Nothing
            Set cmdDel = Nothing
            Set colField = Nothing
        End If
    Next
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    MsgBox numDel & " records deleted" & vbLf & _
           numIns & " records inserted", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")  
End Sub

Function BuildSQL(ws As Worksheet, ByRef colField) As String
    Dim lastcol As Long, i As Long, ph As String, fname As String
    Dim f As String, sql As String, sep As String
    With ws
       lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       For i = 1 To lastcol
            fname = .Cells(1, i)
            If Len(fname) > 0 Then
               colField.Add i, fname ' column number
               f = f & sep & "[" & fname & "]"
               ph = ph & sep & "?" ' parameter placeholders
               sep = ","
            End If
       Next
    End With
    BuildSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo." & ws.Name & _
               " (" & f & ") VALUES (" & ph & ")"
End Function

Function BuildCreateSQL(ws As Worksheet) As String
    Dim lastcol As Long, i As Long, fname As String
    Dim f As String, sql As String, sep As String
    With ws
       lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       For i = 1 To lastcol
            fname = .Cells(1, i)
            If Len(fname) > 0 Then
               If i = 1 Then
                   f = f & sep & "[" & fname & "]" & " bigint"
               Else
                   f = f & sep & "[" & fname & "]" & " varchar(255)"
               End If
               sep = ","
            End If
       Next
    End With
   
    BuildCreateSQL = "CREATE TABLE dbo." & ws.Name & _
               " (" & f & ", CONSTRAINT pk_" & Replace(ws.Name, " ", "_") & _
               " PRIMARY KEY ([" & PK & "]))"
End Function

Function NoHash(s As String)
    Select Case Left(s, 1)
        Case "#", "_", "'"
            NoHash = Mid(s, 2)
        Case Else
            NoHash = s
    End Select
End Function

Function DbConnect(SERVER As String, DBNAME As String) As ADODB.Connection   
    Dim s As String
    s = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & SERVER & _
              ";Database=" & DBNAME & "; Trusted_Connection=yes"
    Set DbConnect = New ADODB.Connection
    DbConnect.Open s
End Function
```

Update the selected cell

```vb
Sub UpdateCell()
    
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
         MsgBox "Select only one cell"
         Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim cmdUpd As ADODB.Command, sql As String, sValue As String
    Dim sTable As String, sField As String, uid As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        sTable = .Name
        sField = .Cells(1, Selection.Column)
        sValue = NoHash(Selection.Value)
        uid = .Cells(Selection.row, 1)
    End With
    
    ' build update command
    sql = "UPDATE [" & sTable & "] SET [" & sField & "] = ? WHERE [" & pk & "] = ?"
    Debug.Print sql, sValue, uid
    
    ' run update
    Set cn = DbConnect("TestServer2019", "Work2023")
    Set cmdUpd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmdUpd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = sql
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adBigInt, adParamInput)
        .Parameters(0).Value = sValue
        .Parameters(1).Value = uid
        .Execute
    End With
    
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    MsgBox sql & " update executed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Im still configuring something but i will mark this as the resolution of my problem, for sure =) But we are right now changing some things in our security so it will be necessary to connect to the database as a specific user. Windows Authentication isnt allowed anymore. Is there a way to implement some kind of hardcode Username and password? Can i change the part with set cn = ... to 
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
User ID=Username;
Password=Password;
Initial Catalog=Database;
Data Source=SQLSERVER;"
cn.Open

Comment: @chewbacca Yes you can do that but I would have thought windows authentication was more secure than plain text passwords in a script. Other way is to configure a DSN with Windows ODBC  Data Source Administrator. Then just use `.ConnectionString = "dsn name"`

Comment: Thank you very much. Ive set up the ODBC Data Source and its working like a charm :) One last thing here in this case: I just wanna add the Primary Key "Row number of article" as a Number. If im sorting right now asc or desc it is showing me the twentytwo e.g. after 21999999. And i dont need the confirmation message boxes. It should automatically run the script so there is no confirmation about tables necessary. And its nice that the Script is scipping the worksheets where A1 is not Row number of article, thank you again.

Comment: No this is the only column which has no #, _ or '

Comment: This is really perfect. Thank you so much, i really appreciate that help. But one last thing is to deactivate the message boxes, so that the script right now is running without giving Information about the progress. Can i just delete the Loop from the msg ?

Comment: @Chewbacca If you want to deactivate a message box then comment it out by adding `'` like `'MsgBox ..`

Comment: I have a question that was coming up the last days: If i am editing one cell the database isnt updating. Is there a way to implement a correction of cells if we have edited a cell in the excel file?

Comment: @Chewbacca Are you running the update macro after the cell change ?

Comment: The Macro is running automatically every morning via Task Scheduler. So is there a way to replace the old wrong entries in the database if the cells are changed?

Comment: @Chewbacca You could use the Worksheet_Change event to automatically run an update query for the  cell that is changed. It gets more complicated if more than 1 line is changed at the same time. Or safer would be macro and a key shortcut like Control-u to update a selected record.

Comment: The problem is that more than one row is changed each time. At least, multiple cells in a row are changed more than once.
Is there any way to implement this scenario in your provided code? The users using the excel file are not able to use a keyboard shortcut each time to update the data. Even if they do, and they forget to update the data, the data is wrong.

Comment: i have talked to our responsible department. You could manage it with the employees so that one cell in a row is changed and then an automatic macro corrects the entry in the database (deletes the old entry and adds the new correct value). All cells that are not yet labeled are automatically inserted by the existing macro. Could you help me with this? Or is there an other way to edit the existing cells in the database?

Comment: @Chewbacca I have added an example of a macro that you can run to update a selected cell. An automatic macro would be difficult to implement reliably. The other way is to use a client like sql management studio.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have an idea:
If we could write the script so that the primary key column B and C are together then I could run a single update script for the cell, otherwise our export would always move the row up or down by one.

As an example.
Column B is an item number and column C is a specific type.
An item number is always assigned a type and together they make the primary key. Everything else in the row can change but these two are unique.